# Another user has modified the record (NAV webservice)

Tags: .net, soap, dynamics-nav-2016

I'm facing an error which I find very hard to debug.

I have a tool that accesses a Dynamics NAV Page service to create and/or update Customers in our Dynamics NAV database.

50% of the time the tool works just fine, the other 50% it doesn't and it always comes with the same error:

Other user has modified "service_name" "No.=CONST(customer_number)"

The problem is that editing in NAV is disabled, so the only thing that possibly could edit records is the tool itself.

When I search the web i get results like "you try to modify the same record twice" and a bunch of NAV code, but I don't have access to the NAV code, and the NAV consultant we're working with is clueless himself.

If someone somehow could point out possible scenario's that don't involve NAV code that would be awesome.

My workflow is as follows:

1. I retrieve the records from NAV
2. I Edit and modify the records where needed
3. I create and/or update the modified records
4. Either this succeeds, or I get the error mentioned above

Either way I call the update method only once in this whole process.

Please help me... I am clueless

Kind regards

Comment: I'd suppose that you need to init record variable properly. Nav is checking timestamp on record when it is inserted/modified. If timestamp is the same in request but changed on SQL this causes the error you are facing.

Comment: Which timestamp is this? I just get a complex type with certain properties assigned to it, i know the NAV key property is very important but i can't seem to find a timestamp.

Comment: Timestamp is on SQL server and not accessible in Nav, it is just used internally. You don't have access to it either. What i'm telling is that you should pay attention on how you initialize you proxy type you are using to access nav record. Most probably it contains timestamp internally.

Comment: VS generated the proxy class... I don't do anything but retrieve the entities... I'm discussing the problem with our NAV consultant also, so hopefully there will be an answer soon...

Comment: Yes VS generates them but it is probably the matter how to use them. If you created a record using an object of proxy class then maybe you need to do something before you can call modify with the same object or same record.

Comment: Aha that way. Ok Thanks, tomorrow the consultant will turn on the NAV debugger also while it's running to see what could possibly the cause.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this problem? I'm facing precisely the same problem. First update on a record is fine, but the next will fail.

Comment: @Aidal This is a very long time ago, but if i recall correctly the issue was the fact that i had to update some data to NAV, but then i continued to work with the same data, without fetching again. That resulted in the error above.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just found out why that was myself the other day. I might as well put in an answer here since the reason isn't well described anywhere or it is hard to find, so chances are one would find it here before anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue myself recently. I'm not sure which version of NAV it is because I'm not really working with NAV myself, just consuming it's web (soap) service.
But I think the issue would be the same in the latest versions as well, since it is not a bug.

Anyway, as I understand it NAV does this in order to uphold the ACID rules of the database.
And in this particular case, NAV is preventing a "dirty write", meaning it is preventing you from updating some data that has been changed into a newer version than the one you have (or say you have).

This may seem odd for someone who just updated an entity and then wants to update it again, knowing nobody else is using the system or working with the data - but there is a simple reason for this.

When you update an entity, you provide a value for it's key attribute. This value does NOT just hold a unique identifier for the entity, but also a timestamp or version description if you wish.
This means that a key value is a "one shot" thing - you can't use it more than once if you are changing the state of entity.

So when you update en entity with the key "abcdefg" (just a sample) it is successful.
But the next time (maybe 5 seconds later) you want to update the entity and use the same key "abcdefg" it will fail with 100% certainty.

So how to fix this, well it's simple because the Update method takes the entity to update as a reference (ref) argument, so once the entity is successfully updated, it will have a new value in it's key attribute and this is the current state of the entity - use this value for the next update and so forth.

This doesn't mean that you always have to retrieve an entity first if you want to update it. The service has a method for checking if it is necessary.

```
service.IsUpdated(obj.Key);
```

If this returns **false**, you can go ahead and update the entity using the key value you have, if **true**, then you need to retrieve a new copy because the entity state described in your key is out-dated.

Hope that made sense and will help others in the same situation that I and the OP were in :)